# Problem with PowerShell nested ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, nested

I am gathering data about emails and exporting to CSV. In this part of the script, I need to generate a text file with what will become 2 columns in the CSV file. The 1st column (email subject line text) already exists in the text file and I need to add the following to every line of the file: a hash tag PLUS part of the file name PLUS a hashtag. Hashtags are my delimiter for the CSV file.

In my first ForEach loop, I iterate through the folder to generate the list of file names, then split to the part of the name that I need. This works. Then in the 2nd ForEach loop, I try to iterate through the files in the folder and add the appropriate file name section to every line. Instead of appending just the one relevant file name section, it appends ALL the filenames to every line.

Here is sample of current data in file "Inbox_Subject_Reports & Timekeeping.txt":

> Re: your weekly business reports Re: submission of timesheet

Desired output:

```
Re: your weekly business reports#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#
Re: submission of timesheet#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#
```

But there are additional files in the same folder, so I am getting all the file names and also the data is copying 4 times:

```
Re: your weekly business reports#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#
Re: submission of timesheet#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#

Re: your weekly business reports#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#
Re: submission of timesheet#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#

Re: your weekly business reports#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#
Re: submission of timesheet#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#

Re: your weekly business reports#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#
Re: submission of timesheet#Reports & Timekeeping.txt#Fourth Quarter Returns#
```

Is is the nesting of my ForEach loops? Do I need some kind of "break" function? I love PowerShell and have been able to do so much with it, but I have hit a limit to my knowledge here. I'd rather learn how to do this correctly than create a cumbersome work-around.

Here is the section of script:

```
$dir = "$Filelocation\Inbox_Subfolders\"
$filelist = @(Get-ChildItem $dir)

ForEach ($file in $filelist){
$folder = $file.Name.Split("_")[2]
}
{
$TextToAdd = "#" + $folder + "#"
$output = @()
$fileContent = Get-Content "$Filelocation\Inbox_Subfolders\Inbox_Subject_*.txt"
}
ForEach ($line in $filecontent){
$output += $line + $TextToAdd
$output | Set-Content "$Filelocation\Inbox_Subfolders\Inbox_Subject_*.txt"
}
```

I've spent days trying to figure out nested ForEach loops and where I am going wrong. I am open to different ways of achieving same results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you double-check that the code you've posted is the actual code you need help with? The big block in the middle surrounded by `{` and `}` would never execute

Comment: While your code contains no syntax errors, I don't think it does what you say it does: There are no _nested_ `foreach` loops, there is a `foreach` loop followed by an orphaned script block `{ ... }`, followed by another `foreach` loop. With proper indenting, that would be more obvious and I encourage you to fix that in the question too.

Comment: Apologies for the seriously inelegant code--this was indeed the latest version of what I was trying to run. I had at least 20 different versions of this trying to see what would work. I didn't know how to separate out the functions that applied to the 1st ForEach and the ones that applied to the next one. Many thanks to Marsze for figuring out what I meant and coming up with a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Use proper indentation. It will make it easier for you to see where nested code blocks start and end.

Does this do what you want?

```bsh
$dir = "$Filelocation\Inbox_Subfolders"

Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter *.txt | foreach {
    $folder = $_.Name.Split("_")[2]
    $TextToAdd = "#" + $folder + "#"
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) | foreach {
        $_ + $TextToAdd
    } | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: This was a great learning experience for me. Sorry my code was wrong for such a silly reason. Very grateful to you for the fix! I will remember my indentations in the future.